# Having trouble to remove an array item in Session on symfony 3.4.*

Tags: php, json, symfony, session, symfony-3.4

For my own cart Management , I created a Cart, CartItem, and CartController classes to manage Items.
A client's cart is something like this (an array of CartItem Object ,on the image below)

**Cart array on session storage**

[image: Cart array on session storage]

And I have some trouble using this function:

```
key = "_cart" , id = an unique identifier for CartItem
$this->session->remove($this->key . '/' . $id);
```

The issue is : when I use the function, it transforms the _cart data to an object like this:

[image: this] .

To RESUME :The cart data was transformed to an object

```
{1:{CartItem1},2:{CartItem2}}
```

instead of expected array like

```
[CartItem1,CartItem2]
```

(e.g for a JSON like representation.) It happens especially when I remove items which are not on the end. It keeps the array format.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The forget method will remove a piece of data from the session. If you would like to remove all data from the session, you may use the flush method:

```
$value = $request->session()->pull('id');
```

OR

```
$request->session()->forget('key');
```

More : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#deleting-data